# how to swallow anything till the semicolon but ignore semicolons in quotes

Tags: antlr4

How to swallow anything till string encounter the semicolon ;  but it should ignore the semicolons in the quotes 
eg. This is example to swallow ';' character.; It should ignore this part.

It should give me This is example to swallow ';' character.;

Comment: Please consider using the right tags

Answer (score 1):

You could use *negative lookbehind* to check if there's a quote:

```
^(?<!['"]).*;
```

Here's a demo on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/u0TLYn/2/